# .htaccess block all ip's, if they are blocked redirect to a page

Tags: .htaccess, ip, block

So I am blocking all ip's except the ones on a list, so how can I redirect people to a new site if they're blocked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My assumption is that you are blocking ip's using allow/deny. I do not believe that you are able to specify a redirect rule to work on the denied ip's as you have told the server to reject their connections outright.

Instead you are going to want to use the RewriteEngine to do a redirect. In case you are unfamiliar with the syntax I have provided the following example which will redirect all ip's except for "72.14.204.99" and "72.14.204.100" to "example.org":

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^72\.14\.204\.99$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^72\.14\.204\.100$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.org/ [R]
```