# Allow directory access to certain IP addresses

Tags: .htaccess, directory, directory-permissions

I am working on a website and I need a directory to be disabled to the public.

I was wondering if there is a way I can redirect all users to a web page, unless I specify a few IP address that are allowed to enter the directory

I don't know much about the .htaccess file, however could I use that to do this?

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this simply with the following code.

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from x.x.x.x
allow from x.x.x.x
allow from x.x.x.x
```

Using the above lines, it's important that you keep the order the same. Denying from all **before** allowing from specific addresses will allow access to only a few IPs while allowing **before** denying will deny access to all.

For more information, try searching google for htaccess deny/allow commands.

Comment: Lol,  I thought you were sending me kisses with the x.x.x.x lol!  How does it work if I have 5 IP addresses I would like to grant permission?

Comment: Ah, as simple as that?  Thanks mate, I'll let you know how I get on

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, if their IP address isn't specified they are to be redirected to a URL! Is that posible?

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348515/htaccess-block-all-ips-if-they-are-blocked-redirect-to-a-page

Comment: I have just used the PHP option, it is only needed for an hour so it will be fine!  Thanks for your time though :)

Comment: A space between 'deny,' and 'allow' may cause Internal Server Error (faced with this issue on Apache 2.0).

Comment: @Olexa Thanks for the tip. Updated